# rainbow text over background color not working css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create rainbow text over a black background...

Why doesnt my code doesnt work?
When plaing with the css it shows up the rainbow text but the background color, and viceversa...

```css
.Bg5{
 background-color: #292F33!important;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)!important;
 
}


.Bg5{font-size:74px!important;
  background-image:
  -webkit-gradient( 
  linear, right top, right bottom, 
  color-stop(0.4, #FB0F64), 
  color-stop(0.7,#D4FE20),
  color-stop(0.8, #6EFF1D) 
  );
  

  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;

   -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;

}
```

```html
<div class="Bg5">Text with rainbow colors</div>
```

Comment: A link listing different methods: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/02/16/create-animated-text-fills/

Comment: ok.I'm checking it out. thanks..how do I fix this background color? I want it to be black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another layer using pseudo-element:

```css
.Bg5 {
  font-size: 74px!important;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,red);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  position: relative;

}

.Bg5:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #292F33;
}
```

```html
<div class="Bg5">Text with rainbow colors</div>
```

Comment: terrific!...but the text color is affected by this black background color right?

Comment: @joe i would say it's the effect of antialiasing and maybe some optical illusion that make think the text is affected by the background

Comment: check out this fiddle please https://jsfiddle.net/fsvv6orq/17/ It is supposed every word have to get the effect not the whole paragraph.

Comment: @joe didn't get you ... you mean what every word ? what did you expect, it seems fine for me

Comment: I mean...I expect every word to have the three colors

Comment: yes...thats awesome...!! I've never expected to get that result by adding `display:inline`...thank you!!